# What is hypervisor and what does it do?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, terminology, hypervisor

I understand that servers are set up to run virtual machines with user applications in cloud settings and will have a hypervisor instead of a host operating system. I was wondering why is the hypervisor used instead of the host operating system?

Answer (score 2):

The hypervisor is used to do the abstraction between the physical and the virtual resources. In other words, it is responsible to create a virtualized layer and share the hardware components (CPU, RAM, NIC, storage) to the virtual machines that will be used. Therefore, it is a lot simpler to centralize and manage multiple sources of heterogeneous elements. It is possible to deploy two types of hypervisors:

**Type 1 Hypervisor:**
There is no actual operating system installed on the [bare metal server](https://www.vmware.com/topics/glossary/content/bare-metal-hypervisor) except the software used to deploy the hypervisor. It is especially used in an enterprise context considering that you maximize the resources to share (you do not have the limitation of running an underlying operating system), but it also possible to deploy one in a home lab if you have the required hardware. A classic example is a [VMWare ESXi host](https://www.vmware.com/ca-fr/products/esxi-and-esx.html).

**Type 2 Hypervisor:**
It consists of installing the hypervisor on top of the actual operating system (Windows, Linux, MacOS). It is used especially for testing, deploying simple services and to extend your software capabilities (you can run multiple different operating systems simultaneously). A classic example is [Oracle’s Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Answer (score 0):

A hypervisor is never used instead of a host operating system. Rather, in the cases where a host operating system is at play, the hypervisor is used ***on top*** of the host operating system to create and manage virtual machines. Without the use of a hypervisor, neither of these operations could be performed.

As the other answer explains, some hypervisors sit directly on top of the host hardware (type 1), while others run as "regular" software in an operating system just like, e.g., a web browser or a record player.

If you're wondering why would someone want to use a type 1 hypervisor instead of a type 2 hypervisor, a simple answer would be because the first setup would consume much less resources, and thus more would be left for the VMs that you want to run.